Cannot bevel an object

The bevel doesn't work properly on these edges.


Hello, maybe bad topology? Could you please share your file?

Please share.. this could be, for example, hidden duplicate vertices or somesuch,.. a share will quickly nail it.

How can i share the file here iam new in it please help

blend-exchange.com

I uploaded the file. How to know you guys got it or not ?? please response if you got this file

Hi, nurul, If you follow the instructions on https://blend-exchange.com/ , the original question-link you pasted in the  text-box will be converted into an image-link to your upload, which you can then edit into your question.

Thank you Robin. I uploaded it successfully. Now please review it and help me to solve the problem. Thank you

Apply the scale in Object mode (otherwise the bevel will be deformed on some axis), select all in Edit mode and M > Merge by Distance to merge the overlapping vertices (otherwise the bevel will be bad) and at last create these edges to avoid the ngon, and the bevel should work fine:

